# prisma_mysql_access denied for the user

Tags: mysql, npm, prisma

in mysql work bench i can create tables, but with prisma access denied for the user i tried to do the push db and prisma migrate dev , in the phpmyadmin i found no users tab, it is a mysql remote from hostinger.

npx prisma migrate dev
Error: Schema engine exited. Error: Command failed with exit code 3221225477: C:\Users\Deniz Bilgisayar\Desktop\programming\vuijs_fastify_prisma\Fastify-Typescript\node_modules@prisma\engines\schema-engine-windows.exe cli --datasource  can-connect-to-database
PS C:\Users\Deniz Bilgisayar\Desktop\programming\vuijs_fastify_prisma\Fastify-Typescript>

npx prisma db push
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": MySQL database "u423016587_tx" at "149.100.151.1:3306"

Your database is now in sync with your Prisma schema. Done in 9.55s

Running generate... (Use --skip-generate to skip the generators)
Error: spawn prisma-prisma-client-js ENOENT

npx prisma migrate dev
Error: Schema engine exited. Error: Command failed with exit code 3221225477: C:\Users\Deniz Bilgisayar\Desktop\programming\vuijs_fastify_prisma\Fastify-Typescript\node_modules@prisma\engines\schema-engine-windows.exe cli --datasource  can-connect-to-database
PS C:\Users\Deniz Bilgisayar\Desktop\programming\vuijs_fastify_prisma\Fastify-Typescript>

i do not know, but i tries to push db and the connection is good with nysql workbench, i run mysql server on docker i couldnot connect to it even with mysql workbench i am losing my job please help.

Comment: DATABASE_URL="mysql://u423016587_tx:password@149.100.151.1:3306/u423016587_tx"